# can't resolve module in sub-directory

Tags: typescript, webpack

I created a new file:

```
src
  graphql
    types
      types.ts
```

the contents in types.ts:

```
export const marge = "marge";
```

but when I try

```
import { marge } from "./graphql/types/types";
```

inside `index.ts` I get the following web pack error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './graphql/types/types'
Any idea why?
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
    var path = require("path");
    module.exports = {
      entry: "./src/index.ts",
      devtool: "inline-source-map",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            use: "ts-loader",
            test: /\.ts?$/
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

The `tsconfig.json` file

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": ["es6"]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can You show tsconfig file ?

Comment: @KrzysztofGrzybek I've added tsconfig

Comment: Hmm sorry, I don't know :P

Comment: It seems the problem is the path, did you try `../graphql/types/types`?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - I was missing

```
resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts'] //resolve all the modules other than index.ts
    },
```

In the webpack config, thus only *index.ts* was being resolved and all other files were skipped.

Comment: In my case, I had already done this, but I forgot that I also had `resolve: { alias: {} }` further down, and the last key wins.